# Are there any problems with initialising the Xamrin Forms object using the application context

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

All guides I have read always refer to initialising the Xamarin Forms object within the context of an activity OnCreate i.e.

```
Forms.Init(context,bundle);
```

But I would much prefer to just register the forms object in the Application object via

```
Forms.Init(App.Context,null);
```

Are there any issues with doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/index):

> Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform UI toolkit that allows developers to efficiently create native user interface layouts that can be shared across iOS, Android, and Universal Windows Platform apps.

So, Xamarin.Forms is just a third part lib for Xamarin.Android. If you want to use it, you need to call `Forms.Init()` method firstly, and call `LoadApplication(new App());` method in Activity.

You should call `Forms.Init()` before call `LoadApplication(new App());`.

Application instance is created at your app start, so you can move `Forms.Init()` to your Application's `OnCreate` method, like this:

```
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Android.App.Application
{
    protected MyApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        Forms.Init(this, null);
    }
}
```

You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/architecture#application-startup) to understand why you need to add the `(IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership)` constructor.

From your code `Forms.Init(App.Context,null);`, I don't know what is `App.Context`. Maybe you mean that `Android.App.Application.Context`?

Answer (score 0):

In a blank Forms app created by VS, the above statement looks as follows:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    ...

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

The `bundle`  argument in the [`Init`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) method seems to be unused; note also the comment:

```
// Provide backwards compat for Forms.Init and AndroidActivity
// Why is bundle a param if never used?
public static void Init(Context activity, Bundle bundle)
{
    ...
```